# List of fractions such that the product of the numerator and the denominator is less than $1988$

Tags: number-theory

> All irreducible positive rational numbers such that the product of the numerator and the denominator is less than $1988$ are written in increasing order. Prove that any two adjacent fractions $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{c}{d}$, $\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}$ satisfy the equation $bc-ad = 1$.

I think using Farey sequences might help since we know that for any positive integer $n$ where $0 \leq a \leq b \leq n$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, if the fractions $\dfrac{a}{b}$ are listed in increasing order, then for two successive terms $\dfrac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $\dfrac{p_2}{q_2}$ we have $p_2q_1-p_1q_2 = 1$.

This question seems to be proving that if $ab \leq 1988$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ where the fractions $\dfrac{a}{b}$ are listed in increasing order, then for two successive terms $\dfrac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $\dfrac{p_2}{q_2}$ we have $p_2q_1-p_1q_2 = 1$.

Can this be generalized to any positive integer and not just $1988$?

Comment: Do you only want the reduced fractions?

Comment: You keep going with $\frac 1{993}$.  The first fraction with $2$ in the numerator is $\frac 2{993}$.  It is between $\frac 1{497}$ and $\frac 1{496}$.  You can verify $bc-ac=1$ in both cases.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think it is closely related to Farey sequences.

Comment: Would you mind answering my question also?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling:  The original question asked about irreducible rational numbers, so the answer is yes.

Comment: I am sure $1988$ is the year the question was asked in and the conclusion is true for any such constant. My thought, not yet successful, is to show that if you have two fractions $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$ with $ab\lt 1988, cd \lt 1988, bc-ad \gt 1$ there is a fraction $\frac ef$ with $\frac ab \lt \frac ef \lt \frac cd$ with $ef \lt 1988$.  If you can prove $\frac {a+c}{b+d}$ is reducible I think you are there.

Comment: As an example, if $bc-ad=2$, you can have all the numbers odd, in which case $\frac {a+c}{b+d}$ has both numerator and denominator even, so you can divide out $2$. The reduced product will be less than $1988$.  Otherwise to have both fractions irreducible you must have $a,c$ odd and $b,d$ even or the other way around.  Either way, again $\frac {a+c}{b+d}$ has both numerator and denominator even.  It doesn't work as well if $bc-ad=3$

Comment: @RossMillikan How is it a contradiction to have a new fraction $\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$?

Comment: We know $\frac ab \lt \frac {a+c}{b+d} \lt \frac cd$, so $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$ cannot be neighboring unless the reduced form of $\frac {a+c}{b+d}$ has product greater than $1987$.  If you can reduce the fraction, the product will be less than $1988$.

Comment: @RossMillikan What is the argument that $\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$ can always be reduced if $bc-ad = c>1$?

Comment: That is what I said I had not succeeded with.  I showed how to prove it if $bc-ad=2$, but I don't have an answer for higher values.  I suspect it is standard, but I haven't found it yet.  It is also why I commented instead of answering.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is this true: Since for any fraction $\dfrac{a}{b}$ in the list we have $ab \leq 1988$, there exists a pair $(a_0,b_0)$ with maximal sum $a_0+b_0$. Any other pairs $(a,b)$ with $a+b \leq a_0+b_0$ must have $ab \leq 1988$.

Comment: No.  The sum $a_0+b_0$ is greater than $1+1988=1989$, but $991$ is prime and $987 \cdot 991 \gt 1988$

Comment: @RossMillikan I am trying to relate this to the theorem about Farey sequences, but I don't see how.